# MySql to MSSQL migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I have a database in mysql that I would like to migrate to mssql since I would like to use that database for an asp.net application.I have everything setup but anytime I try to convert the schema using SSMA(SQL Server Migration Assistant) I keep getting this error

> An unexpected error occured.Please send the log file to the product support."For more information see getting SSMA assistant"

in the product documentation.

> Error Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How do I get that out of the way and then migrate the data to MSSQL.

Comment: I would recommend doing what the error message says. "Please send the log file to the product support."For more information see getting SSMA assistant" in the product documentation."

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue. Once I installed the latest version of ssma for mysql, it resolves the issue you have mentioned above.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51218